# JavaMelody Overhead instead of JMX

Tags: java, tomcat, filter, overhead

I am looking for a Monitoring tool for tomcat.
I found the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242958/best-tools-to-monitor-tomcat

I noticed JavaMelody and installing it took only 10 minutes. 
However, I have the following question which results from having added JavaMelody as a filter in web.xml,

Doesn't this mean that all requests go through JavaMelody before reaching my servlet?
So this adds an additional overhead to process every request.

This seems at first to me to be a deal breaker for production servers handling large numbers of requests. Comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really think that javamelody users can write and give their own answer(s).

Meanwhile, some information is available about [javamelody overhead in production](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/Overhead).

It seems to me that javamelody overhead is not a deal breaker. (I am the author of javamelody)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I imagine you are using concurrent hashmaps (and other threadsafe data structures) to store the information in memory related to the requests. I will download the source code and have a look at what is going on inside.

Comment: I had a look at both the reviews, and the source code, as well as deploying on a development machine and stress testing. It is not a deal breaker after all.